# change label values when an entry value is changed

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, label

My problem at the moment is I am trying to change a label(label 16) to the first value of entry_values[0] which isn't working I have tried passing it in as a variable and many other things, after about an hour of research  I couldn't find a solution.I think the main problem is that it sets the label before the code with the entry is run so that it wont change. when I set it to a textvariable it produces an empty string (I think) but when I use just text it puts in a 0 where I expect my number.

```
 def sub_menu(root):
    global subpage
    subpage = Frame(root)
    button5 = Button(subpage, text="Save Generation Data",
                 command = lambda: save_entries())
    button5.grid(row = 1, column = 6, sticky = E)

    button6 = Button(subpage, text="Return To Main Page",
                 command = lambda: switch_page("main"))

    button6.grid(row = 0, column = 6, sticky = W)

    juveniles_label0 = Label(subpage,text="Juveniles")
    adults_label1 = Label(subpage,text="Adults")
    seniles_label2 = Label(subpage,text="Seniles")
    population_label3 = Label(subpage,text="Population (Thousands)")
    survival_rate_label4 = Label(subpage,text="Survival Rate (Between 0 and 1)")
    birth_rate_label5 = Label(subpage,text="Birth Rate")
    number_of_gens_label6 = Label(subpage,text="Number of Generations")
    disease_trigger_label7 = Label(subpage,text="Disease Trigger Point")

    global entry0
    entry0 = Entry(subpage)
    global entry1
    entry1 = Entry(subpage)
    global entry2
    entry2 = Entry(subpage)
    global entry3
    entry3 = Entry(subpage)
    global entry4
    entry4 = Entry(subpage)
    global entry5
    entry5 = Entry(subpage)
    global entry6
    entry6 = Entry(subpage)
    global entry7
    entry7 = Entry(subpage)
    global entry8
    entry8 = Entry(subpage)


    juveniles_label0.grid(row = 0, column = 1) 
    adults_label1.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
    seniles_label2.grid(row = 0, column = 3)
    population_label3.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    survival_rate_label4.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    birth_rate_label5.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    number_of_gens_label6.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
    disease_trigger_label7.grid(row = 4, column = 0)

    entry0.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    entry1.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
    entry2.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
    entry3.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    entry4.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    entry5.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
    entry6.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    entry7.grid(row = 3, column = 3)
    entry8.grid(row = 4, column = 1)



    return subpage

def save_entries(): #entry recieve point 
    save_page = Frame(root)

    """ if e0 < 0:
           make a check to check if value is < 0 dont accept and if a value  is inputed or not using if type(string_name) == str """
    e0 = entry0.get()
    if e0 >= 0:
        entry_values[0] = (e0)
    e1 = entry1.get()
    if e0 >= 0:
        entry_values[1] = (e1)
    e2 = entry2.get()
    if e0 >= 0:
        entry_values[2] = (e2)
    e3 = entry3.get()
    if e0 >= 0:
        entry_values[3] = (e3)
    e4 = entry4.get()
    if e0 >= 0:
        entry_values[4] = (e4)
    e5 = entry5.get()
    if e0 >= 0:
        entry_values[5] = (e5)
    e6 = entry6.get()
    if e0 >= 0:
        entry_values[6] = (e6)
    e7 = entry7.get()
    if e0 >= 0:
        entry_values[7] = (e7)
    e8 = entry8.get()
    if e0 >= 0:
        entry_values[8] = (e8)

    print entry_values


    return save_page


def display_values(root):
    sub2 = Frame(root)
    global entry_values


    label8 = Label(sub2, text = "Juveniles")
    label9 = Label(sub2, text = "Adults")
    label10 = Label(sub2, text = "Seniles")

    label11 = Label(sub2, text = "Population(Thousands)")
    label12 = Label(sub2, text = "Survival Rate(Between 1 and 0)")
    label13 = Label(sub2, text = "Birth Rate")
    label14 = Label(sub2, text = "Number of Generations")
    label15 = Label(sub2, text = "Disase Trigger Point")

    label16 = Label(sub2, text = entry_values[0])
    label17 = Label(sub2, textvariable = entry_values[1])
    label18 = Label(sub2, textvariable = "")
    label19 = Label(sub2, textvariable = "")
    label20 = Label(sub2, textvariable = "")
    label21 = Label(sub2, textvariable = "")
    label22 = Label(sub2, textvariable = "")
    label23 = Label(sub2, textvariable = "")
    label24 = Label(sub2, textvariable = "")


    button7 = Button(sub2, text="Return To Main Page",
                 command = lambda: switch_page("main"))


    label8.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    label9.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
    label10.grid(row = 0, column = 3)
    label11.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    label12.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    label13.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    label14.grid(row = 3, column = 3)
    label15.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
    label16.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    label17.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
    label18.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
    label19.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    label20.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    label21.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
    label22.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    label23.grid(row = 3, column = 3)
    label24.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

    button7.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    return sub2
```

Comment: Actually the main problem is that your code contains too much stuff unrelated to the issue and that makes it difficult for you (and us) to find and fix it. Try to reduce it to a [mcve] and probably you will solve it by yourself or else you will have better chances to get an answer here.

Comment: ill change that asap but the reason I like to leave it in is because sometimes I cut out too much or people don't know where I get values or where stuff is defined. But I will cut out the un-needed stuff.

Comment: Please read the link. Carefully. If the example is complete and verifiable you won't have cut too much.

Comment: A simple way to know if you've cut too much: the code won't run and won't reproduce the problem. Until that happens, keep removing code. If the problem is with one entry and one label, remove all of the other entries and labels.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the text of a label you can do:

```
label["text"] = textVar
```

or

```
label.config(text=textVar)
```

So in your above code, when the entry changes, reconfigure the label using one of the above options.

Comment: this isn't really what I'm looking for I need to be able to pass though the list or something similar but I cant give it to display_values where I am trying to pass them in through. its most probably a simple error