# My Tkinter GUI wont open

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
list_ = [0,0]
menu = ""
subpage = ""


def main_menu(root):
    print list_
    menu = Frame(root)
    button0 = Button(menu, text="Go To Subpage",
                 command=lambda: switch_page("sub"))
    button0.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    button1 = Button(menu, text="Save Values",
                 command=lambda: save_values())
    button1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    global entry0
    global entry1

    entry0 = Entry(menu)
    entry1 = Entry(menu)

    entry0.pack()
    entry1.pack()


    return menu


def sub_menu(root):
    subpage = Frame(root)

    label0 = Label(text = list_[0])
    label1 = Label(text = list_[1])

    label0.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    label1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    button2 = Button(subpage, text="Return To Main Page",
                 command = lambda: switch_page("main"))
    button2.grid(row = 0, column = 0)



    return subpage

def save_values():
    list_ = []
    e0 = entry0.get()
    list_.append(e0)
    e1 = entry1.get()
    list_.append(e1)
    print list_

def switch_page(page_name):
    slaves = root.pack_slaves()
    if slaves:
        slaves[0].pack_forget()
    pages[page_name].pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root = Tk()
pages = {
    "main": main_menu(root),
    "sub": sub_menu(root),

}

switch_page("main")
root.mainloop()
```

So my problem is that the GUI won't open I have tried putting it into another new python file and have tried to re-write it but slightly differently, which now won't open as soon as I  use a .grid() function, once this .grid() function is removed it will show the GUI. Anyway for this code I am not sure in the slightest what is preventing it from opening because the research I have done has lead to me finding out I need to use root.mainloop() ,which I was already using and the other solution was to define the frame length and width which I thought was unnecessary because I had previously had the GUI working and not only that I have a frame created with widgets inside.
Any help is appreciated.

Also on side note in the switch page function I use the .pack_forget() function and was looking to see  if there was a function which closed the page fully or would allow me to change a label while the page is open like a sort of refresh function(update idle task didn't work for what I needed it for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use both `grid` and pack with windows that share the same parent. You are doing that here:

```
...
button0.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
...
entry0.pack()
entry1.pack()
```

You can mix and match `grid` and `pack` all you want within an application, but you can't use them both like you do because those widgets all have `menu` as a parent.

Also, you can change the attributes of any widget with the `config` method (eg: `some_widget.configure(background="red")`). You need to have a reference (variable) to that widget.

Comment: The first bit worked perfectly and I did try the second suggestion but I think my problem is that the labels won't change as I am using pack_forget() which I am not sure whether it updates the labels correctly your suggestion did change the label but once the label changes I don't think it will change the value after initialisation

Comment: @2C00L4U: I don't quite understand your comment. You absolutely can change the text on a label after initialization. That's a very common thing to do. I don't understand what that has to do with `pack_forget` other than if you call `pack_forget` on a label, it won't be visible any more so even if you change the text you won't see the change.

Comment: I am not very good at this, you can probably tell, but with my code I have tried so much to try and change it that I jut presumed there was a bit of code that is used to change the label text that I hadn't found but now I am thinking there is and issue with my code if you want to look at it I will link it you to here: stackoverflow.com/questions/39853463/… If you need any extra code just ask me but I haven't a clue why it isn't changing the label after initialisation this problem has been bugging me for around three weeks I appreciate any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853463/change-label-values-when-an-entry-value-is-changed this is the link